# Please help message box doesnt accept parameter

Tags: c++

I've got this function, but it does not work:

```
std::string s(Buffer);
std::string::size_type k = 0;
while ((k = s.find('"', k)) != s.npos) {
    s.erase(k, 1);
}
while ((k = s.find(' ', k)) != s.npos) {
    s.erase(k, 1);
}
::MessageBoxA(NULL, s.c_str, "Print recevied buffer", MB_ICONINFORMATION);
```

I've got a buffer(which is a internet page), and I want to parse it in order to remove all of the spaces and the char '"'. I've tried many solutions but none of them work.
This one says that I should create a reference to the string, but I don't understand what that means.

Comment: What's wrong? What errors? What have you tried?

Comment: "it doesn't work" is _not_ an acceptable problem description.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote `s.c_str` (naming a function pointer) instead of `s.c_str()` (actually calling the function).

Comment: Hope everything goes smoothly with you madam~

Comment: Thank you so much! it works now! but i still didnt solve my problem i could use a bit of more help . Now i've this buffer and in this page there' s a public ip i've to retrieve in a varialbe and i can do that, i used a method where i go till the point of the string starts and try to retrieve it, but doesn' t work. this is a fragment of the page where the ip is :</div>

    <div class="info">
      <article class="hero clearfix">
        <div class="col_100">
          <div style="text-align:center"><h1>Your Public IP Address Is:</h1>

  <div id="up_finished">

5.66.123.345  </div></div>

Comment: Stop! This isn't a chat room.... this is not really how SO is supposed to be used.....

Answer (score 1):

Your actual problem involves using `k` without resetting it.

```
while ((k = s.find('"', k)) != s.npos) {
    s.erase(k, 1);
}

k = 0; //you need to reset k in order to properly remove spaces

while ((k = s.find(' ', 0)) != s.npos) {
    s.erase(k, 1);
}
```

Comment: I didn't add the () after c_str and that was the problem thanks m8! i could use a bit more help, can you read my answer to lightness? thank you in advance!

Comment: @VincentTerra No.  One distinct question per thread.